# Is there any function for finding ranks in ranks in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three  table which have four column and in all of these based on some criteria. I have to found top 100 leads in all these which I achieved it  using rank function in oracle sql.
But my problem is now I have to further split them down.Say I got top 300 leads from these 3 tables (top 100 from all three),now I have a column say it has value 4.
So I have to take lead one by one from these 300 leads  in priority order.top 1 from first table,top 1 from second table, top 1 from third table then again top 1 from first table. Is there any way to achieve this in oracle sql

Comment: Maybe someone understands that question; I don't. OK, 3 tables, top100 rows from each of them make result set of **300 rows** (you call them "leads"). Then, you have to take "lead" one-by-one from these **400** (?! 400? Don't you have 300 rows?) in "priority order". What is "priority order"? Finally, if you take "top 1" from the 1st table (and 2nd and 3rd) and then **again top 1** - well, there's only one "top 1". Perhaps it would help if you illustrated it with some examples.

Comment: Out of these 300 leads , assume there are 5 leads that can be assigned to one person,then leads have to be in one by one of this ordering sequence,1st lead from 1st table,2nd lead from 2nd table,3rd lead from 3rd table ,4th lead from 1st table,5th lead from 2nd table . Hope this will clarify

Comment: "Hope this will clarify" It does not. Talking about the problem generally is not sufficient because we cannot see your data or know what you expect and it is confusing. Please [edit] the question an include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (ensure this is **minimal**, so if you can give an example with 5 rows instead of 100 rows per table then do so); **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; the expected output for your sample data; and an English (not code) explanation of why that sample data is produced.

Comment: What if you add a "source" column in the query calculating the rank() in each table being 1, 2, 3 according the order you want to give to the rows depending on the table they come from, then the result could be the "JOIN" of the 3 tables on the RNK and the whole result sorted by RNK and SRC: SELECT .. FROM (SELECT FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.RNK : t2.RNK JOIN T3 ON T1.RNK = T3.RNK) ORDER BY RNK, SRC ?

Answer (score 0):

You can unified the data and set a custom table priority (depending on your needs) and rank the data again, using your current row ordering and the new column. It will look like this:

```
SELECT *    
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordPriority, TablePriority) AS FilteringColumn
FROM
(

    SELECT t1.*
          ,RANK AS RecordPriority
          ,1 AS TablePriority
    FROM T1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t1.*
          ,RANK AS RecordPriority
          ,2 AS TablePriority
    FROM T1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t1.*
          ,RANK AS RecordPriority
          ,3 AS TablePriority
    FROM T1

) DS
```

Then you can use the `FilteringColumn` to get the rows easily.

Comment: First of all thanks for answering this question,but I have a doubt,after getting three ranks I have to split it in 3 sequences that two one by one in order. How to achieve this?? because no 4 was just an example value can be any number